# Converting m4a to highest quality wav and 320kbps mp3

Tags: audio, converters, wav, m4a, audio-converter

I have a file .m4a audio file of size **805 kb** which I wanted to convert it to wav. My purpose is to (1) get highest quality .wav audio file and (2) get 320 kbps .mp3 audio file.

I used an online service (https://www.online-convert.com) to convert it. When I converted directly **without optional settings**, the file size increased to **11.6 mb** and when I converted the same audio with optional settings like, changing bit resolution to 32 Bit and changing sampling rate to 96000 Hz, the file size jumped to **50.7 mb**

There are only two optional settings in the web service

Bit resolution - no change, 8 bit, 16 bit, 24 bit, 32 bit

Sampling rate - no change, 1000 hz, 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000, 96000 hz

And one raido button for Normalize audio that can be checked and unchecked

Can someone explain why the file size increases and what settings I must keep to get the highest quality from the original 805 kb audio?

Thanks

Comment: You can't improve the quality of audio once it has been recorded. Changing the bit resolution or sample rate won't magically make the sound better. wav files aren't compressed so they are bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to check exact bit rate and sample rate of a recorded m4a audio so that I can convert it to .wav or .mp3 with exact bit/sample

Comment: Like most compressed formats the bit rate varies. You just need the bit resolution and the sample rate which lots of programs will display. Note that since mp3 is a lossy format converting to that **will** lose more information.